# Entropy of X given Y given Z

Tags: probability, entropy

I want to compare $H(X|Y)$ and $H(X|Y,Z)$.
It's known that $H(X) \ge H(X|Y)$. Can I say that $H(X|Y) \ge H((X|Y)|Z) = H(X|Y,Z)$?

Comment: Yes, this is true. You can prove it in almost the same way as proving $H(X) \ge H(X \mid Y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given three random variables $X,Y,Z$ consider,

$$I(X:Z|Y)=H(X|Y)-H(X|Y,Z)$$

where $I$ is Kulback Leibler Divergence. By positivity of KL divergence, we have

$$H(X|Y)-H(X|Y,Z) \ge 0$$

Comment: Why does $I(X:Z|Y)=H(X|Y)−H(X|Y,Z)$?

Comment: $I(X;Z|Y)= \sum \limits_x \sum \limits_z P_{XZ|Y}\log_2 \frac{P_{XZ|Y}}{P_{X|Y}P_{Z|Y}}$. Now split the logarithm after decomposing the distribution in the numerator and you will see you get what you need.